# How do you enter hex values into a terminal program that is already running?

Tags: assembly, terminal, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am currently trying to debug a program in gdb, and I am at a point where the program takes user input. I want to enter hex values into this input to test out a buffer overflow for a CTF to send me to (example) memory address *0x12345678*.

I have only found examples of people online trying to enter hex as an argument when initially running the program by using a *perl* command, but I want to enter hex after the program has already started. I also already know how to set register values manually in gdb, but that is not what I am trying to do.

I found something close in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1307773/), which works for *netcat*, but when running gdb with the same method, it seems to make itself a background process that no longer works when going back in with *fg*.

Basically, how do I give an already running program in the terminal hex input?

Comment: It's unclear what you want but you can do `run < file-with-data`. You can also attach gdb to the program running in separate terminal (or a shell that will launch it) and use whatever method you normally use.

Comment: I assume you mean binary data, like the 4-byte value represented by the 8 hex digits `12345678`.  Because it's trivial to type actual ASCII strings of hex digits on a terminal, like as an input to a program that uses `strtol` or `scanf("%d"`

Comment: If your terminal is 8-bit clean you might be able to paste binary data from the clipboard.  e.g. from `xclip -i -selection clipboard  foo.bin`, or pipe into it.  (e.g. probably xterm or Konsole / Gnome-terminal locally are 8-bit clean, but maybe not over SSH with OpenSSH's default of using `~` as an escape sequence, like `~.` to close a session, or `~~` for a literal tilde.)

Comment: You can test things out by running `hexdump -C` and pasting into its stdin.  I just tried it in KDE Konsole on my Arch Linux desktop.  `printf "\x04\x05\x06"" | xclip -i -selection clipboard` then `hexdump -C` and shift-insert.  It opens up a dialog box warning me about the control characters in what I'm about to paste, and lets me paste them raw or strip them out.  But `\x04` is control-D, the EOF character for "cooked" input, and hexdump doesn't put the terminal into raw mode.  Pasting doesn't bypass that, which is what I was testing by including a 04.

Comment: oops, copy/paste error in my last comment, the double quotes should match the arg to printf.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, I appreciate your help. I installed KDE Konsole and the results looked a little more promising at first because I could actually paste hex characters that I copied using the xclip method, but it doesn't seem like it's able to reproduce the correct hex when pasted into hexdump. I tried with a few different sets of hex values and it could only reproduce normal ASCII symbols reliably, i.e. letters/numbers. I tried with the printf method you used, as well as with perl.

Also, if I need to use 0x0a, which is newline, that sends the input prematurely. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Didn't see your reply earlier since you didn't @peter notify me.  You could use `stty raw < /proc/<PID>/fd/0` (assuming the terminal is its stdin) before pasting to put the terminal in raw mode, for programs that don't already do that (like `less` or `vim`).  That will potentially make a `read` system call return after just one byte, though, depending on how the past goes through.  And if its' already started a canonical-mode read with line-editing and newline or control-D to "submit", having another process put the TTY into raw mode might not work for that read.

Comment: Reading from a pipe (perhaps from a hex undump program) would avoid all the Unix TTY issues with trying to paste raw binary data.  Like perhaps `xxd -r | ./a.out` but then you'd have to type *everything* in hex.  Maybe a program that can process escape sequences (like C string literals) could be a good filter.

Comment: (Hrm, `xxd -r` I think is looking for a hexdump with addresses, so maybe not that exact program.)